# Break text inline list

Tags: css, list, scroll, overflow, inline

I have a problem with a horizontal list. I have 200px sized li elements inside a 800px ul. I want the ul to scroll horizontally, and the text inside the li to break. This causes the li elements to lose their vertical position.

HTML:

```
 <div>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three</li>
        <li>four</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Kinda hard to describe.. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yrLtsLrf/

Comment: try to use `white-space:pre-wrap;` class inside your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `vertical-align: top;` to your `li`.

Comment: Thanks! Such a simple fix, works just as I imagined :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you need to

```
vertical-align:top
```

and add to li

```
whitespace:normal
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrLtsLrf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

add below css to li will work.

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```